# EUICCManager.isEnabled() is always return false

Tags: android, euiccmanager

```
Device: meizu 18pro
OS Version: Android 11

EuiccManager mgr = (EuiccManager) context.getSystemService(Context.EUICC_SERVICE);
boolean isEnabled = mgr.isEnabled();
// isEnabled always is false
```

https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/esim-overview

I implemented an LPA application according to the steps in the official documentation. The application has all the required permissions, APK is placed in **/system/priv-app/**, but **EUICCManager.isEnabled()** always returns false.

Documents described in the add **android.hardware.telephony.euicc** features, on the LPA will return true, now I have to add, and use the **PackageManager.hasSystemFeature()** returns true.

I have tried on several devices and all of them are false. I wonder if it is the reason that the device does not support eSIM.

**I hope you can get help from all the great gods!**

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!
I upgraded the target SdkVersion to 31 and added subscription